# Using Orbax to checkpoint flax `TrainState` with new `CheckpointManager` API

Tags: python, jax, flax

**Context**

The [Flax](https://flax.readthedocs.io/) docs describe [how to checkpoint a `flax.training.train_state.TrainState`](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/training_techniques/use_checkpointing.html) with orbax. In a nutshell, you set up a `orbax.checkpoint.CheckpointManager` which keeps track of checkpoints. Next, you use the `CheckpointManager` to save the state to disk. Summarising the code snippets from the Flax docs:

```py
import orbax

# <-- Code building an empty and a full chkpt. -->.
abstract_chkpt = ...
chkpt = ...

orbax_checkpointer = orbax.checkpoint.PyTreeCheckpointer()
save_args = orbax_utils.save_args_from_target(ckpt)

options = orbax.checkpoint.CheckpointManagerOptions(max_to_keep=2, create=True)
checkpoint_manager = orbax.checkpoint.CheckpointManager(
    '/tmp/flax_ckpt/orbax/managed', orbax_checkpointer, options)

# Save and restore a checkpoint.
checkpoint_manager.save(step, ckpt, save_kwargs={'save_args': save_args})
checkpoint_manager.restore(1, items=abstract_ckpt)
```

The notebook provided by the Flax docs does what I want: periodically track `TrainState`, which can then be restored.
However, when executing the code provided by the Flax docs warn that this orbax checkpoint API is deprecated:

> WARNING:absl:Configured `CheckpointManager` using deprecated legacy API. Please follow the instructions at https://orbax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_refactor.html to migrate by May 1st, 2024.

The link indicated by the error message gives some pointers how to use the new `orbax.checkpoint.CheckpointManager`.

**Question**

How do I save and restore a Flax `TrainState` with the new `orbax.checkpoint.CheckpointManager` API?

Here is my failed attempt (based on the [Orbax migration instructions](https://orbax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_refactor.html)) at saving and restoring a trivial `flax.training.train_state.TrainState`:

```py
import orbax.checkpoint as obc
from flax.training.train_state import TrainState

abstract_ckpt = TrainState(step=0, apply_fn=lambda _: None, params={}, tx={}, opt_state={})
ckpt = abstract_ckpt.replace(step=1)

# Set up the checkpointer.
options = obc.CheckpointManagerOptions(max_to_keep=2, create=True)
checkpoint_dir = obc.test_utils.create_empty('/tmp/checkpoint_manager')
checkpoint_manager = obc.CheckpointManager(checkpoint_dir, options=options)
save_args = obc.args.StandardSave(abstract_ckpt)

# Do actual checkpointing.
checkpoint_manager.save(1, ckpt, args=save_args)

# Restore checkpoint.
restore_args = obc.args.StandardRestore(abstract_ckpt)
restored_ckpt = checkpoint_manager.restore(1, args=restore_args)

# Verify if it is correctly restored.
assert ckpt.step == restored_ckpt.step  # AssertionError
```

My guess would be that the problem relates to `save_args`, but I haven't managed to pinpoint the problem and figure out a fix. Any suggestions how to correctly restore the checkpoint using the new `CheckpointManager` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created `save_args = ocp.args.StandardSave(abstract_ckpt)` instead of `save_args = ocp.args.StandardSave(ckpt)`, so you're just saving the wrong thing.

Also note that `checkpoint_dir = ocp.test_utils.create_empty('/tmp/checkpoint_manager')` is a bit unnecessary - it's just a test utility for deleting a directory if it already exists - makes running our colabs a bit easier. Probably you shouldn't need to use it in real life, as the `create` option in `CheckpointManager` will create the directory for you.